# Scroll view not working when ad banner pushed up by keyboard

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my project i have ads sitting at the bottom of the screen and the app functionality near the top in which the user has to enter data. When the user enters the data the banner ad moves up to sit on top of the keyboard. This covers part of the functionality on top and so i want to implement a scroll view so the user can still access all inputs and buttons while the keyboard is up. I have tried to do this and its hasn't worked yet

I have been testing it on my samsung device and in emulators on my computer and followed similar questions to no prevail

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            "Functionality in here"
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the bit inside the linear layout were i have written "functionaility here" to scroll when the ad is pushed up by the keyboard instead of covering part of it and it not scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the user enters the data the banner ad moves up to sit on top of the keyboard. This covers part of the functionality on top and so i want to implement a scroll view so the user can still access all inputs and buttons while the keyboard is up.

According to your description, you mean that ad banner overlaps some control when user want to enter data, so you use Scrollview, but it still overlaps.

I suggest you can add this lines  to your current LinearLayout.

```
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
```

I do one demo that you can take a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:paddingBottom="50dp">

  <EditText 
       android:id="@+id/editText1" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


  <TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/load_interstitial_button"
      android:text="@string/interstitial_button_text"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText3"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText4"
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText5"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText6"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText7"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText8"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText9"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/test_banner_ad_unit_id" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

You can see the ad banner have some space with Linearlayout, so it will not overlaps any controls.